# Fourier and Laplace transforms (Forster's Hydrodynamics book)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, correlation-functions, laplace-transform

In Forster's hydrodynamics textbook, he defines the following Fourier transform and (one-sided) Laplace transform
\begin{align}
S(k,\omega) =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt e^{i\omega t} S(r,t) \\
\tilde{S}(k,z) =& \int_0^\infty dt e^{izt} S(k,t) \qquad \text{ (for $\operatorname{Im}z$ > 0)}
\end{align}
(corresponding to Eqns. 2.15 and 2.16, where $S$ is a correlation function). He then goes on to claim
\begin{align}
\tilde{S}(k,z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d\omega}{2\pi i} \frac{S(k,\omega)}{\omega - z}
\end{align}

How does he obtain this last equation? In particular, I am confused at how one obtains a one-sided transform (i.e. integral over the positive reals) from the two-sided transform. If I plug in $S(k,\omega)$ and perform contour integration on $d\omega$ (with the upper infinite semicircle), then I almost recover $\tilde{S}(k,z)$, but the limits of integration are wrong for $dt$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Jordan's lemma correctly? Remember that you can only close the contour in the upper half-plane if $t$ has  the correct sign. Otherwise you need to use a lower-half-plane semicircle, and so get zero as there is no pole within the contour.